# Check if each number in a vector is between some numbers in another vector in R

Tags: r, intervals

Say I have two vectors, A and B. A has 15 variables and B has 28 variables.

```
A = c(13,14,29,31,32,39,42,51,59,61,68,91,102,109,120)

B = c(26,26,28,29,30,30,33,38,41,42,45,46,47,47,49,49,80,81,86,86,90,90,92,100,101,105,105,107)
```

I want a 14 by 27 matrix, Z, where a i by j entry is 1 if (B_j,B_{j+1}] overlaps with (A_i, A_{i+1}].

For instance, the (3,4) entry of Z would be 1 since (29,31] and (29,30] overlap, with 30 as a common number. Is there a fast way to compute this?

I have the following code:

```
Z = matrix(0, length(A)-1, length(B)-1)
for (i in 1:(length(A)-1)){
  nn = which(B > A[i] & B <= A[(i+1)])
  if (length(nn)>0){
    Z[i,(nn-1)] = 1}}
```

It works well but my A and B vector often contain 30,000+ elements and it is incredibly slow. Making of the matrix Z even takes unnecessarily long time. Can anyone help with this?

Ideally, there is a vectorized solution to this or a well written function from a package that can do this like cutting a cake.

Comment: If the vectors "often contain 30,000+ elements", are you sure you want a matrix as result? It will be huge. However, check `?findInterval`.

Comment: Thanks nicola, some sort of a vector, list, or a matrix is necessary as I will be using the output for other computation.

Comment: In your code, it seems you are checking if `(B_j, B_j]` overlaps with `(A_i, A_i+1]` and not `(B_j, B_j+1]`? "IRanges" package is useful for these things; the `queryHits()` and `subjectHits()` of `findOverlaps(IRanges(A[-length(A)], A[-1L]), IRanges(B[-length(B)], B[-1L]))` should be row/col indices of "1"'s in your "Z".

Comment: Thanks alexis, I will try

Comment: Wow findOverlaps is ridiculously fast. Thank you.

Comment: Others (including me) would be interested in your solution. Maybe you can post an answer as well. Also check out Matrix:sparseMatrix for storing your results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If closed Intervals `[B_j,B_{j+1}]` and `[A_i, A_{i+1}]` are ok for you as well you could use

```
A <- as.integer(c(13,14,29,31,32,39,42,51,59,61,68,91,102,109,120))
B <- as.integer(c(26,26,28,29,30,30,33,38,41,42,45,46,47,47,49,49,80,81,86,86,90,90,92,100,101,105,105,107))

DT_A <- data.table(A0 = A, A1 = shift(A, type = "lead"), key=c("A0", "A1"))[-length(A)]
DT_B <- data.table(B0 = B, B1 = shift(B, type = "lead"), key=c("B0", "B1"))[-length(B)]

ind_true <- foverlaps(DT_A, DT_B, type="any", mult="all", which=TRUE)[!is.na(yid)]

mat <- matrix(0, length(A)-1, length(B)-1)
mat[ind_true$xid, ind_true$yid] = 1
```

Comment: This is fantastic. I was trying to implement foverlaps and couldn't make it happen. Is there any way to make it (B_j,B_{j+1}] and (A_j, A_{j+1}] ?

Comment: You could run foverlaps 3 times. 1st as above, then to check for B_j=A_{j+1} and finally to check for A_j=B_{j+1}. Or implement it your self end file a pull-request at https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table

Answer (score 3):

Here's an option using matrix multiplication. As commented the matrix can get big, and you'll have to see if the speed improvement is worth it:

```
res1 <- outer(A, B, FUN = function(A, B){B > A})
res2 <- outer(A, B, FUN = function(A, B){B <= A})
dim(res1); dim(res2)
res3 <- (res1[-nrow(res1),] + res2[-1,]) == 2
image(res3)
dim(res3)

op <- par(mfcol=c(1,2))
image(Z, main="Z")
image(res3, main="res3")
par(op)
```

[image]

Comment: this is ~5x faster than my answer

Comment: Thanks Marc. It seems like my loop version runs faster than your code though. Perhaps, I should be using findOverlaps as alexis suggested?

Comment: You may want to compare a larger example. I must admit though, your loop script looked pretty good. Loops aren't necessarily slow, especially when you set up your results vector beforehand (as you have done)

Comment: Thanks Mark. I used a sample with 10,000 for A and 70,000 for B. I will lastly try IRanges suggested by Alexis.

Comment: I also tried a larger example - my version takes twice as long as your. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

This answer uses matrix indexing and relies on `expand.grid` though there are much faster implementations of it.  You lag your vectors to create matrices of A and B, then with a function that does simple boolean check, we can index into the matrices with an expanded grid.  Then it returns a matrix.

```
overlap = function(id,x1,x2){
  idA = id[,1]
  idB = id[,2]
  o = (x1[idA,1] >= x2[idB,1] & x1[idA,1] <= x2[idB,2]) | (x1[idA,2] >= x2[idB,1] & x1[idA,2] <= x2[idB,2]) |
    (x1[idA,1] <= x2[idB,1] & x1[idA,2] >= x2[idB,1]) | (x1[idA,1] <= x2[idB,2] & x1[idA,2] >= x2[idB,2])
  matrix(o,nrow=nrow(x1))
}

A = c(13,14,29,31,32,39,42,51,59,61,68,91,102,109,120)
nA = cbind(lag(A),A)[-1,]

B = c(26,26,28,29,30,30,33,38,41,42,45,46,47,47,49,49,80,81,86,86,90,90,92,100,101,105,105,107)
nB = cbind(lag(B),B)[-1,]

expand.grid.jc <- function(seq1,seq2) {
  cbind(Var1 = rep.int(seq1, length(seq2)), 
    Var2 = rep.int(seq2, rep.int(length(seq1),length(seq2))))
}

ids = expand.grid.jc(1:nrow(nA),1:nrow(nB))
overlap(ids,nA,nB)
```

Comment: I didn't see the open/closed bands, but this is pretty straight forward

Comment: Thank you Mark for your input